# iPhone webkit dialer not working

Tags: iphone, webkit

I've a simple dialer like this
<a class="call" href="tel:18000000000">1 (800) 800-0000</a>

It's not doing the call out.
Do I need to set anything before that will work?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1):

I've only used UIWebView with the `detectsPhoneNumbers` property set to YES, which means you don't need to put the `<a>` tag around phone numbers. Did you check that property?

With iPhone OS 3.0 and later, you should use `UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber` in the `dataDetectorTypes` property.

But if you're just writing HTML and not a Cocoa app, you probably want it to be like:

`<a class="call" href="tel://18000000000">1 (800) 800-0000</a>`

Make sure to include the slashes.